# Is Indian Flapshell Poisonous

Tags: safety, turtles

I have one Indian Flap shell turtle in my home. Is it a poisonous pet? I'm concerned if it bites children (or even adults). What is the risk to my family?

Comment: What makes you think it might be poisonous?  I scanned the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_flapshell_turtle) and don't see anything about poison there.

Comment: Poisonous is where you ingest and get poisoned, do you mean venomous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In TurtleForum they happen to ask the same question as you did in one of their [threads](http://www.turtleforum.com/forum/upload/?showtopic=112164)(search near the bottom):

> Yes, softshelled turtles are generally extremely aggressive, have very
>   long necks, and inflict painful wounds. **No turtle in the world is
>   venomous** (i.e. they do not have venom glands and an apparatus to
>   inject a toxic substance like a cobra would). There are a few species
>   of turtles that are known to eat extremely toxic grasses, mushrooms,
>   etc. without harm to themselves but can store these toxins in their
>   meat/fat. If the turtle is killed and eaten it is possible for the
>   predator (human) to be poisoned. There are a few rare examples of
>   human deaths from circumstances of this nature. An uncleaned wound of
>   any kind has the potential to develop into a bacterial infection which
>   could be extremely dangerous if left untreated.

So you're okay OP. Just clean your wound in case the turtle happens to bite you.

Comment: So Shall I let to move free inside home with kids ? It also loves to be attached with me

Comment: Well I don't know that, since I don't know much about turtle behavior. @DarshnaRaval

Comment: OK Anyway he is let free to roam inside home too....he is also too much attached with me and my kids....